# How to show all taxonomies within custom post type loop

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to show all records for a particular custom post type and I want a list of all taxonomies in a dropdown.

Here is the query for the CPT:

```
<?php 
        $articles = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'stories',
      ));
?>
```

And getting the terms

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'topic',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
?>
```

Then the loop

```
<?php if ($articles->have_posts() ):
while ($articles->have_posts() ): $articles->the_post();
?>
// this is where I want to echo all taxonomy names
 <div class="masonry__item col-lg-3 col-md-6" data-masonry-filter="<?php //echo tax names here ?>">

<?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You mean only those terms assigned to the current post? And you want it like so: `Category 1, Category 2` (separated by comma) or is it by *slug* like so: `category-1 category-2` (separated by space)

Comment: No, I want to list all records for the custom post type and I also want to list all taxonomies associated with the custom post type. I am using isotope filter. So, the custom post type records show in columns and above is a filter dropdown with the taxonomy names. So, If I click on one of those then it will only show posts for that taxonomy name

Comment: I don't want it to be outputted with commas etc. I want to put the names in any container I want whether it be in a <li> or <option>. I just want the names.

Comment: There are differences between 'taxonomy' and 'term' - e.g. in your case, the taxonomy is 'topic' and a term inside that could be 'Topic 1', 'Topic 2', etc. So are you sure you want to list the *taxonomy* names and not *term* names? And do you want the names or the slugs (e.g. for a term, name: 'Topic 1', slug: 'topic-1')?

Comment: Ah, right. Yes, I am looking for the term names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering the `<?php //echo tax names here ?>`:

1. In the loop, you can get the post terms using [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/):

   ```php
   while ($articles->have_posts() ): $articles->the_post();
     $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'topic', [ 'fields' => 'names' ] );
   ```
2. Then you can do something like `echo implode( ' ', $terms );` inside the `<div>` tag:

   ```php
   <div class="masonry__item col-lg-3 col-md-6"
     data-masonry-filter="<?php echo implode( ' ', $terms ); ?>">
   ```

But are you very sure you want to use the term *name* and not *slug*?

If you want the term slug, then you'd use `'fields' => 'id=>slug'` and not `'fields' => 'names'`.

Comment: Nice one, thanks!